# execute sql server agent job task in ssis error : Failed to lock variable"RunIs" for read access with error 0xC0010001

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-job

I am using `SQL Server 2016` and `SSIS`. I have a package in which I am calling a sql server job.

My job have just one step as `PowerShell command` for transfering all files from one directory to another directory between two servers.

When I run my job from SQL server, it works well.

When I run my package from `VisualStudio`, every things is ok, but after deploying my project to sql server, when I want to run this package from SQL Server, I have this error :

> Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task: Error: Failed to lock variable "RunId" for read access with error 0xC0010001 "The variable cannot be found. This occures when an attempt is made to retrive a variable from the Variable collection on a container during execution of package, and the variable is not there. The variable name may have changed or the variable is not being created.".

[image]

I deleted the `Execute sql server agent job task` from my package and I redeployed my project and now I do't have this error. It is clear that error is about `Execute sql server agent job task`.

I have more than 2000 files in source directory and it takes several minutes to transfer all files to destination directory.

**Edit1** : I have several Task and component in my package and the last ones is `Execute sql server agent job task` and i don't have `Execute T-SQL Statement Task`.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any `Execute T-SQL Task` in there?

Comment: does this help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107766/failed-to-lock-variable-ssis-error

Comment: I don't use the "Other Tasks"/DBA tasks much as they're ... limited in use for me. You can click the View TSQL button and you'll see the task is generating `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id=N'DEADBEEF-DEAD-BEEF-DEAD-BEEFDEADBEEF' so I'm not sure where the RunId is getting referenced from. Since your package is so trivial, could you try just creating a new SSIS package with the single task and connection manager and see whether the problem persists?

Comment: @TheGameiswar: I have read this article. It is not my case. I have not deleted the variable or I don't have two component which are using the same variable. And i dont have this error when i run my package from VisualStudio.

Comment: @Hackerman: I have several Execute SQL Task in my package The last task in my package is Execute sql server agent job task

Comment: @billinkc I have created a new package and I have put just one `Execute sql server agent job task`. I have the same problem and the same error message.

Comment: Ok Ardalan....now if you look at the properties of the `Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task` you'll see that one of the properties is called `RunId` with an value like `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`; now right click on your package and choose `View Code`...and Ctrl+F and look for `RunId`...for some reason(bug maybe) that value is not setted in the XML...what you can do and since that task relies on the `sp_start_job` procedure, you can just add an execute sql task that call the `sp_start_job` procedure instead of the agent job task...